# Cascading combo box/List box - Multiple select Items results (Power Apps)

Tags: drop-down-menu, powerapps, cascading

This might be simple but i could not figure out. 
My issues is: I have cascading drop down with name
Project code and project name.
I have used combox for both so that i can select multiple items.
problem here is, if i select one items in project code, project name combo box shows the items but when i select multiple items in project code. Project name combo does not shows items for both multiple items.

formula i have used are: 
project code

```
Items: Code.Activeprojectcode
update: ComboProjectCode.Selected.Activeprojectcode
```

Project Name

```
Items: Distinct(Filter(Code,Title=ComboProjectCode.Selected.Activeprojectcode),Projectname)
update: ComboProjectName.Selected.Result
```

Any suggestion would be great

[Cascading Dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHp5u.jpg)